# A question about polynomial rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

This may be a trivial question.  We say an ideal $I$ in a ring $R$  is $k$-generated iff $I$ is generated by at most $k$ elements of $R$. Let $F$ be a field. Is it true that every ideal in $F[x_1,x_2,....,x_n]$ is $n-$generated. (This is true when $n=1$, because $F[x_1]$ is a PID)

Second question: Is it true that every ideal in $F[x_1,x_2,x_3,...]$ is generated by a countable set of elements of $F[x_1,x_2,x_3,...]$ ?

Thank you

Comment: As F is Noetherian, K = F[x1,..xn] is also, so every ideal in K is f.g., and <x1, x2...xn,2 > ideal generated in C[x1,..xn], this is generated by n+1 elements, am I wrong some where?

Comment: @Ram: if $2 = 0$ then that ideal is generated by $n$ elements; if $2 \neq 0$ then it is invertible, so that ideal is the unit ideal and is generated by one element.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, I do this stupid mistake every time I talk about $C[x]$

Comment: @YACP I am self studying abstract algebra (still a beginner). Thus, many of the terms that were mentioned in my previous question (like Krull's dimension, Hillbert Samuel polynomial...) I never heard of. As a result I didnt really digest Cohen's theorem.

Comment: @YACP The reason why I asked this question is the following: I wanted to find an analouge to the division algorithm in $F[x,y]$. I conjectured that for any polynomials $f(x,y),p(x,y),q(x,y)$ (p,q relatively prime) there exists polynomial $g(x,y)$ such that $deg(g)< max\{deg(p),deg(q)\}$ and $f-g\in(p,q)$.

Comment: @YCAP Finally, I was hoping that I could use this to show that every ideal $I$ in $F[x,y]$ is 2-generated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to the first question is no. For example, the ideal $(x^2, xy, y^2)$ in $F[x, y]$ cannot be generated by $2$ elements. To see this, note that any set of generators must *linearly* span the subspace of homogeneous quadratic polynomials, which has dimension $3$.

Comment: I see. Any thoughts about the second question

Comment: Is there a function $f(n)$ such that every ideal in $F[x_1,x_2,...,x_n]$ is $f(n)$ generated ?

Comment: Qiaochu's example can be easily generalized: consider the ideal generated by all monomials of degree $d$. Their number is unbounded as $d$ grows.

Comment: I am not sure what the answer for radical ideals is though.

Answer (score 4):

Since Qiaochu has answered your first question, I'll answer the second: yes, every ideal $I\subset F[x_1,x_2,x_3,...]$ is generated by a countable set of elements of $F[x_1,x_2,x_3,...]$.

Indeed, let $G_n\subset I_n$ be a **finite** set of generators for the ideal $I_n=I\cap F[x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_n]$ of the **noetherian** ring $F[x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_n]$.
The union $G=\bigcup_n G_n$ is then the required  denumerable set generating the ideal $I$.
The reason is simply that every polynomial  $P\in I$  actually involves only finitely many variables $x_1,...,x_r$ so that $P\in  F[x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_r]$ for some $r$ and thus, since $P\in I_r$, one can write $P=\sum g_i\cdot f_i$ for some $g_i\in G_r\subset G$ and $f_i\in F[x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_r]$.
This proves that $G$ generates $I$.

Comment: Yes. I also figured another solution. I will put it shortly (+1)

Answer (score -3):

An ideal is finitely generated if it is finitely generated as $R$-modulo. So your first statement is wrong because there are at least the base-ring. For your second question note that Hilbert basis theorem say that if $R$ is a noetherian ring also $R[x]$ is a notherian ring. But you know that notherian rings are finitely generated as $R$-moduli.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know Hilbert basis theorem and I still didnt study moduli

Comment: I can't make sense of your second and fourth sentences. In the third sentence the theorem you invoke is not the basis theorem, and anyway  has no relevance to Amr's second question.

Comment: $R[x_1,x_2,...]$ is not Noetherian, take the ascending chain of ideals $ (x_1) \le (x_1, x_2) \le (x_1,x_2,x_3)...$ has no maximal element.